# pattern matching algorithm for large database of dna

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

is there any preexisting efficient algorithms in pattern matching (large data of DNA)?

there are so many algorithms like Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm, Boyer-Moore algorithm, Index based forward backward multiple pattern algorithms are there but they are efficient and performs very poor when the is large. so please help me to know about efficient algorithms in pattern matching...

Comment: can you be more specific what you mean by 'they are efficient and perform very poorly' ? What is the size of your pattern and the size of your string where you want to find the string ? Do you have additional storage where you could keep additional data derived from your string to be searched ?

Comment: they are effiecient for small size of strings (1000 chars) but when comes to larger size of string(lakhs of chars) they performs poorly...  we can have additional storage for derived data from given string the string conatins only 4chars a,c,t,g(dna)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [BLAST algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this must have been discussed elsewhere.

I guess you'll already store the strings using two bits only (rather than using eight bits per character). Not only does this reduce the storage size by a factor four (I guess your strings can be as long as hundreds of millions of characters) but also reduces the time to transfer this data (e.g. from disk to memory or from memory to the CPU cache).

The following assumes that there are a lot of queries while the strings to be searched remain the same, so calculating and storing some additional quantities based on the strings is justified.

- I suggest you have a look at [suffix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) which can be constructed in linear time using [Ukkonen's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm).
- If that is not feasible, maybe you should consider a hybrid approach like building a fixed set dictionary of all possible words up to a fixed length L and divide your string to be searched into regions.

  - for each word in the dictionary store the region indices in which they appear (include L-1 characters of the next region when building this list)
  - when searching for a word, split it into strings of length L and check in which regions these appear. Assuming that the maximum search string length does not exceed the length of a region, your search string can only appear in regions where all parts (of length L) of your search string appear (or are in the preceding/following region)
  - with a standard string searching algorithm, search only the resulting regions for your search string
    (this is probably similar to what a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) does)

For the second approach, you'll need to tune the parameters (the length L of the words in the dictionary and the size/number of regions).